# gqlgen failing to recognize custom type

Tags: go, gqlgen

My `gqlgen` models:

```
models:
    Int64:
        model:
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
    ID:
        model:
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.ID
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int32
    Int:
        model:
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int32
            - github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql.Int64
```

in schema.graphql:

```
type Value{
    t: Int64!
}
```

I keep getting : `failed to load schema: graph/schema.graphqls:97: Undefined type Int64.` and I'm unsure as to why. I tried adding a custom type myself and referencing that in `models`

```
func MarshalInt64(t int64) graphql.Marshaler {
    return graphql.WriterFunc(func(w io.Writer) {
        _, _ = io.WriteString(w, strconv.FormatInt(t, 10))
    })
}

func UnmarshalInt64(v interface{}) (int64, error) {
    if res, ok := v.(json.Number); ok {
        return res.Int64()
    }
    if res, ok := v.(string); ok {
        return json.Number(res).Int64()
    }
    if res, ok := v.(int64); ok {
        return res, nil
    }
    if res, ok := v.(*int64); ok {
        return *res, nil
    }
    return 0, fmt.Errorf("could not convert %v of type %T to Int64", v, v)
}
```

But same problem happens. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was, seems like you need to add the custom type directly to your schema.

Adding `scalar Int64` to my `schema.graphqls` fixed the issue.